# Updating the icon of every JLabel in a JLabel ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, swing

I want to update every icon of a `JLabel` `ArrayList`, to its own individual icon based off of an outside `ArrayList`. The outside `ArrayList` is called `_board_`, and the `JLabel` `ArrayList` is called `_tiles_`. I want to update every icon to its corresponding item in `_board_`. How can I do that efficiently? I need it to update every icon of a huge list, we're talking like 100 - 200 items long. Right now, at a hundred items long, it takes about 4 seconds before displaying all of the icons at the same time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
    //this is all one line:
    tiles.get(i).setIcon(resizeIcon(displayTile(board.get(i), 
    tiles.get(i).getHeight(), tiles.get(i).getHeight()));
}
//this resizes the ImageIcon and returns the risized icon:
public static ImageIcon resizeIcon(ImageIcon i, int x, int y) {
    Image image = i.getImage();
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(x, y, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
    i = new ImageIcon(newimg);
    return i;
}
//this returns an ImageIcon based off of the number that is put in:
public static ImageIcon displayTile(int num) {
    if (num != 0) {
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src/resources/" + num + ".png");
        return i;
    }
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("src/resources/0.png");
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Cross posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49932952/how-do-you-update-icon-of-every-jlabel-in-a-jlabel-arraylist-efficiently

Comment: There is one closing parenthesis missing in the body of the `for` loop. It should probably be after `board.get(i)`. I presume `board` is an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1):

We will start by cleaning up the code:

First, let's make the for loop cleaner to read. A compiler is able to inline variables that are only used once in a scope.

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {

    final ImageIcon tileToDisplay = displayTile(i); 

    final int height = tiles.get(i).getHeight();
    final ImageIcon resizedTileToDisplay = resizeIcon(tileToDisplay,height,height);
}
```

Second, in `displayTile(int num)`, StringBuilder is more efficient when concatenating strings. Also, `if(num != 0)` is redundant because you apply the same logic in both cases.

```
public static ImageIcon displayTile(int num) {

    final StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder("src/resources/");
    pathBuilder.append(num);
    pathBuilder.append(".png");

    return new ImageIcon(pathBuilder.toString());
}
```

Lastly, `resizeIcon` changes the parameter `i`; methods should not change the parameters that they receive:

```
public static ImageIcon resizeIcon(ImageIcon icon, int x, int y) {

    Image resizedImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(x,y,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    return new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
}
```

Now, let's deal with performance:

You are loading 100 - 200 images from a file, resizing each one and then placing it on a screen. This is a resource intensive task and you need to optimise it. Here are some suggestions

1. Use a [`ThreadPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to load the images asynchronously on start up. Cache them in memory and use them as needed.
2. Only load images as needed. For example, the board may have 200 tiles, but only 10 are visible at a given time. So load the first ten tiles. Anticipate which tiles will be needed and load them as necessary
3. If resizing is a one time operation, perhaps saved the resized images to disk so that you won't have to resize them after the first time.
4. BufferedImage offers [`getSubimage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). You could have one big image with all 100-200 tiles. Load this one big image once, and then show only the relevant part of the image using `getSubimage`. This is a concept known as Sprites and you can find a clearer example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).